# Calculating multinomial logit model prediction probabilities

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mlogit

***Please try to give parameterize solution (there are more than three alternatives).***

I have a dict with beta values:

```
{'B_X1': 2.0, 'B_X2': -3.0}
```

And this data frame:

```
 X1_123  X1_456  X1_789  X2_123  X2_456  X2_789
   6.75    4.69    9.59    5.52    9.69    7.40
   7.46    4.94    3.01    1.78    1.38    4.68
   2.05    7.30    4.08    7.02    8.24    8.49
   5.60    7.88    8.11    5.98    4.60    1.39
   1.80    8.28    9.16    7.34    7.69    6.16
   3.73    6.93    8.93    2.58    3.48    6.04
   8.06    8.88    7.06    6.76    4.68    7.82
   5.00    7.29    5.86    3.92    5.67    4.10
   2.49    2.55    4.66    7.15    6.26    7.87
   1.50    3.35    5.70    9.86    4.83    1.17
   8.19    7.72    9.56    6.61    4.15    3.64
   2.43    9.54    9.15    4.41    9.18    7.85
   2.71    3.24    4.56    6.22    7.89    9.93
   5.96    4.34    5.26    8.63    9.81    9.40
```

`123`, `456`, and `789` are the alternatives.

I want to calculate the prediction probability using this formula:
[image]

`j`, `k`, and `s` are the mentioned alternatives.

Expected result:

```
 X1_123  X1_456  X1_789  X2_123  X2_456  X2_789  P_123  P_456  P_789
   6.75    4.69    9.59    5.52    9.69    7.40  0.490  0.000  0.510
   7.46    4.94    3.01    1.78    1.38    4.68  0.979  0.021  0.000
   2.05    7.30    4.08    7.02    8.24    8.49  0.001  0.998  0.001
   5.60    7.88    8.11    5.98    4.60    1.39  0.000  0.000  1.000
   1.80    8.28    9.16    7.34    7.69    6.16  0.000  0.002  0.998
   3.73    6.93    8.93    2.58    3.48    6.04  0.024  0.952  0.024
   8.06    8.88    7.06    6.76    4.68    7.82  0.000  1.000  0.000
   5.00    7.29    5.86    3.92    5.67    4.10  0.210  0.107  0.683
   2.49    2.55    4.66    7.15    6.26    7.87  0.038  0.623  0.339
   1.50    3.35    5.70    9.86    4.83    1.17  0.000  0.000  1.000
   8.19    7.72    9.56    6.61    4.15    3.64  0.000  0.005  0.995
   2.43    9.54    9.15    4.41    9.18    7.85  0.041  0.037  0.922
   2.71    3.24    4.56    6.22    7.89    9.93  0.981  0.019  0.001
   5.96    4.34    5.26    8.63    9.81    9.40  0.975  0.001  0.024
```

Probabilities sum should be 1 in every row.

**Please try to give parameterize solution (there are more than three alternatives).**

Expected result with constant for each alternative:
`{'B_X1': 2.0, 'B_X2': -3.0, 'B_123': 0.1, 'B_456': 0.2, 'B_789': 0.3}`

```
 X1_123  X1_456  X1_789  X2_123  X2_456  X2_789  P_123  P_456  P_789
   6.75    4.69    9.59    5.52    9.69    7.40  0.440  0.000  0.560
   7.46    4.94    3.01    1.78    1.38    4.68  0.977  0.023  0.000
   2.05    7.30    4.08    7.02    8.24    8.49  0.001  0.998  0.001
   5.60    7.88    8.11    5.98    4.60    1.39  0.000  0.000  1.000
   1.80    8.28    9.16    7.34    7.69    6.16  0.000  0.002  0.998
   3.73    6.93    8.93    2.58    3.48    6.04  0.021  0.952  0.027
   8.06    8.88    7.06    6.76    4.68    7.82  0.000  1.000  0.000
   5.00    7.29    5.86    3.92    5.67    4.10  0.180  0.102  0.717
   2.49    2.55    4.66    7.15    6.26    7.87  0.034  0.604  0.363
   1.50    3.35    5.70    9.86    4.83    1.17  0.000  0.000  1.000
   8.19    7.72    9.56    6.61    4.15    3.64  0.000  0.005  0.995
   2.43    9.54    9.15    4.41    9.18    7.85  0.034  0.034  0.932
   2.71    3.24    4.56    6.22    7.89    9.93  0.978  0.021  0.001
   5.96    4.34    5.26    8.63    9.81    9.40  0.970  0.001  0.029
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

Turn columns into a MultiIndex

```
df = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1, inplace=False)
```

And define your `B` such that the keys match the prefixes in `df`

```
B = {'X1': 2.0, 'X2': -3.0}
```

Then

```
def f(b, x):
    return np.exp((b * x).sum(1))

parts = f(B, df.stack()).unstack()

preds = parts.div(parts.sum(1), axis=0)

df.join(pd.concat({'P': preds}, axis=1).round(3)).pipe(
    lambda d: d.set_axis(map('_'.join, d.columns), axis=1, inplace=False)
)

    X1_123  X1_456  X1_789  X2_123  X2_456  X2_789  P_123  P_456  P_789
0     6.75    4.69    9.59    5.52    9.69    7.40  0.490  0.000  0.510
1     7.46    4.94    3.01    1.78    1.38    4.68  0.979  0.021  0.000
2     2.05    7.30    4.08    7.02    8.24    8.49  0.001  0.998  0.001
3     5.60    7.88    8.11    5.98    4.60    1.39  0.000  0.000  1.000
4     1.80    8.28    9.16    7.34    7.69    6.16  0.000  0.002  0.998
5     3.73    6.93    8.93    2.58    3.48    6.04  0.024  0.952  0.024
6     8.06    8.88    7.06    6.76    4.68    7.82  0.000  1.000  0.000
7     5.00    7.29    5.86    3.92    5.67    4.10  0.210  0.107  0.683
8     2.49    2.55    4.66    7.15    6.26    7.87  0.038  0.623  0.339
9     1.50    3.35    5.70    9.86    4.83    1.17  0.000  0.000  1.000
10    8.19    7.72    9.56    6.61    4.15    3.64  0.000  0.005  0.995
11    2.43    9.54    9.15    4.41    9.18    7.85  0.041  0.037  0.922
12    2.71    3.24    4.56    6.22    7.89    9.93  0.981  0.019  0.001
13    5.96    4.34    5.26    8.63    9.81    9.40  0.975  0.001  0.024
```

Wrapped in one pretty function

```
def f(df, b):
    d = df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1, inplace=False)
    parts = np.exp(d.stack().mul(b).sum(1).unstack())
    preds = pd.concat({'P': parts.div(parts.sum(1), axis=0)}, axis=1).round(3)
    d = d.join(preds)
    d.columns = list(map('_'.join, d.columns))
    return d

f(df, B)

    X1_123  X1_456  X1_789  X2_123  X2_456  X2_789  P_123  P_456  P_789
0     6.75    4.69    9.59    5.52    9.69    7.40  0.490  0.000  0.510
1     7.46    4.94    3.01    1.78    1.38    4.68  0.979  0.021  0.000
2     2.05    7.30    4.08    7.02    8.24    8.49  0.001  0.998  0.001
3     5.60    7.88    8.11    5.98    4.60    1.39  0.000  0.000  1.000
4     1.80    8.28    9.16    7.34    7.69    6.16  0.000  0.002  0.998
5     3.73    6.93    8.93    2.58    3.48    6.04  0.024  0.952  0.024
6     8.06    8.88    7.06    6.76    4.68    7.82  0.000  1.000  0.000
7     5.00    7.29    5.86    3.92    5.67    4.10  0.210  0.107  0.683
8     2.49    2.55    4.66    7.15    6.26    7.87  0.038  0.623  0.339
9     1.50    3.35    5.70    9.86    4.83    1.17  0.000  0.000  1.000
10    8.19    7.72    9.56    6.61    4.15    3.64  0.000  0.005  0.995
11    2.43    9.54    9.15    4.41    9.18    7.85  0.041  0.037  0.922
12    2.71    3.24    4.56    6.22    7.89    9.93  0.981  0.019  0.001
13    5.96    4.34    5.26    8.63    9.81    9.40  0.975  0.001  0.024
```

Comment: Very cool, but if I have more than two variables and betas, may you show me how to implement this solution in parameterize way?

Comment: There is more than one way to interpret what you mean as "parameterize".  Please show an example of what you mean.  IMO, what I've provided is parameterized in that I've provided a function that takes parameters.

Comment: If I have X1, X2, ..., X20, so I want to avoid writing them manually. Let's assume we have list of `[X1, X2, ..., X20]`, so we can use this.

Comment: See if that helps.

Comment: Last question, if I have constants for each alternative: `{'B_X1': 2.0, 'B_X2': -3.0, 'B_123': 0.1, 'B_456': 0.2, 'B_789': 0.3}`, how can I add it? (See expected result with constants.)

Comment: That complicates the issue.  `B`'s values can now refer to multiple columns.  I've spent enough time on this, I have to move on now.  My apologies.